# How can I run Midnight Commander opening an ftp connection on launch?

Tags: command-line, server, ftp, midnight-commander

As the question itself says: I would like to know if there is a way to create a script or direct command line to run midnight commander `mc` and request the program to open an ftp connection on -let's say- the right panel?

Something like:

`mc --open-ftp user@ftp.server.com:password --right-panel`

Or something like that.

I have seen this tutorial and it works indeed: [Save Connection Settings in Midnight Commander](http://www.piotrnowicki.com/2012/11/save-connection-settings-in-midnight-commander/), but this allow me to have a bookmark list of my sites, which I must invoke just after running midnight commander.

Any ideas?

Comment: When I `cd` to a server from MC, it opens a ftp connection in the selected panel, for example `cd /ftp://ftp.midnight-commander.org`. However, I couldn't figure out how to make it start it on launch (adding the command to `~/.local/share/mc/bashrc` did not work, it was simply ignored). I think the best you'll be able to do is to make a user menu entry for it and then be 2 key-press from the ftp instead of 0. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

```
mc leftpanel [ rightpanel ]
```

left panel:

```
xfce4-terminal -x mc   ftp://user:password@example.com
```

right panel:

```
xfce4-terminal -x mc . ftp://user:password@example.com
```

Comment: Puff.... The real thing. Thank you very much. Tried this on Ubuntu 20.04 and works like a charm. Just need to make sure the username is the right one. Certain shared hosting service providers requires to use the user@domain.ext format for the username. I really appreciate a lot your time.